# Discord.js music bot getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this code for my music bot:
[my code](https://pastebin.com/028wmPQA)
It runs ok but after playing 5-6 songs I get this error:

```html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
    at play (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test bot\index.js:201:36)
    at execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test bot\index.js:162:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:6152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6152) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and it stops playing. How do I fix this
thanks in advance!

Comment: This error seems to indicate that `serverQueue` is undefined in your `play` method, which means `queue.get(guild.id)` is also undefined in that method. Either the `queue.get` method is broken or some logical error/miscalculation causes the queue to never be set through `queue.set` in the first place. I can't see where the `queue` variable is defined in your code, nor can I see the code or module for `queue`, so I can't really help beyond that.

Comment: I updated the paste on pastebin, it now includes all the music part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this part of the code (in the `execute` method) is what causes the issue:

```
try {
    var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    queueContruct.connection = connection;
    play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
    return message.channel.send(err);
  }
```

What is happening is that an error occurs within the `try` block. I do not know what causes that error, it could be something like an error occurring when the bot tries to join the voice channel. But when that error occurs, the `catch` block is executed, and the `catch` block deletes the queue for the guild as well as attempts to send the error as a message. Now this actually causes both errors that you are experiencing. The `play` method is not able to read property `connection` of undefined because it is trying to do `serverQueue.connection`, but your `catch` block has deleted the `serverQueue`. And the DiscordAPI Error ("Cannot send an empty message") is the result of attempting to send a message containing the `err` object, which is an object and not a string (thereby causing Discord to try and send an empty message).

To fix the first issue, you might want to change several things. First, make sure to check if your bot is already in a voice channel (or the voice channel it is trying to join) in the `try` block using `if` statements. If your bot tries to join a voice channel when it is already in said voice channel, an error will occur which will cause your issue to occur. Second, do not just delete the queue in the `catch` block. You should probably cause the bot to leave the voice channel it is currently in first and end any instances of executing `play` methods in the current guild, so that the issue does not repeat itself. To fix the second issue, instead of doing `message.channel.send(err)`, try doing `message.channel.send(err.stack)`. This should ensure that it is a String and not an Object that is being sent as a message to the channel.

You may need to do some additional debugging on your own to find what is actually causing an error within the `try` block. Once you've done that, preventing the recursive `play` method from continuing to function even after the queue is deleted is what you need to do. You may even want to avoid using the try/catch altogether, if it is possible to utilize the `.catch()` method on a specific action (such as joining the voice channel) that returns a Promise (I do not know if `voiceChannel.join()` returns a Promise but if it does, you should probably use `.catch()`).